# ERROR 1932 (42S02): Table 'xxx.wp_users' doesn't exist in engine

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

After upgrading to Mariadb. I got this error and can't access anymore my database:

> ERROR 1932 (42S02): Table 'xxx.wp_users' doesn't exist in engine

Using: mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.34-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

`ibdata` located at `/var/lib/mysql/` have correct permission:

```
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 12582912 Aug 7 01:21 ibdata1 
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 52428800 Aug 7 01:21 ib_logfile0 
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 52428800 Aug 5 17:10 ib_logfile1
```

I am stuck and don't know what else to do. Any help is welcome

Comment: ok deleted it on SE

Comment: I successfully dropped the tables. Created another table and repopulated the tables manually. However if I repopulate directly with .frm files it does not work, if I do it with .sql file then no problem. Since I don't have all .sql backup files I need to find a better solution.

Comment: I have a database corruption issue. Although I have the .frm and .ibd files it is impossible for me to dump them. I have tried all the suggestions I found on the net.

Comment: What do you see in `/var/lib/mysql/xxx` ?

Comment: Any clues in the mysqld.err?

Comment: in /var/lib/mysql/xxx I see multiple files including *.opt *.frm *.ibd

Comment: Permissions on `xxx` and the files in it?

Comment: -rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql all files are related to WP (wp_users.frm, wp_user.ibd...)

Comment: [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table xxx/wp_users from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.] in the sys log